# import declaration are not working in Vue app.js file in Laravel-6, editor PHP Storm (Where i want to import vue-router)

Tags: vue.js, laravel-6

I'm importing vue-router in app.js file but it says import is deprecated in currently used JavaScript version.

I've also tried to import vue-router in another js file (index.js under router folder) got the same problem.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

import declaration is not supported by currently JavaScript version

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have got solution for this problem, there was JavaScript version problem in PHP Storm editor, Solution was : by pressing **Ctrl+Altr+S** key->then from Languages & Frameworks and select JavaScript version which needed.